# How do I configure the insert file target in nano?

Tags: macos, nano

The [GNU nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/) text editor has the ability to insert another file into the current file (`^R`). The behaviour of this command can be modified to insert the file into a new buffer with `M-F`.

I would like the default behaviour of `^R` to be inserting the file into a new buffer. I have somehow accomplished this on several computers that I use, however I am unable to accomplish this on Mac OS X Mavericks with GNU nano 2.2.6 (latest stable version) installed via Homebrew.

Is there any nano configuration option to set this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is really quite simple, just include the line `set multibuffer` in your `.nanorc` file.